# Excel online: link to specific row or cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink, links

**Goal:**

I would like to create a link that opens an Excel sheet in Excel online at a specified row or cell to help the user to find a specific entry in several thousand rows without filtering, searching or scrolling forever. Sure, Excel isn't the right tool for what we are doing; however, I don't have the power to change that...

**Link:**

The structure of the following link works to open the Excel sheet in Excel online, but at a random location:

```
https://company.sharepoint.com/teams/folder/folder/folder/filename.xlsm?web=1
```

The following link works for opening the sheet in the specified cell, but not in the browser:
(answer from this questions: [Specify a specific worksheet to open for a Microsoft Excel workbook using a hyperlink](https://superuser.com/questions/205728/specify-a-specific-worksheet-to-open-for-a-microsoft-excel-workbook-using-a-hype) or [Link to a row or cell in an excel sheet via URL](https://superuser.com/questions/998158/link-to-a-row-or-cell-in-an-excel-sheet-via-url))

```
https://company.sharepoint.com/teams/folder/folder/folder/filename.xlsm#sheetname!a22
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to modify the query in the link to do both at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Link to Range

The **Link to this Range** feature may do what you want. I was able to link to a specific cell with this, and the Excel file opened in the browser instead of in the app.

Steps:

- Highlight the range of cells (1)
- Right click (with mouse) (2)
- choose "Copy Link" > "Range" (3, 4)
- (grant permission to access clipboard if needed (5))
- Wait a moment
  [image: steps to copy a link in excel]
- This will open a window with the option to copy the link and change permissions of the link.
  [image: Copy link]

There will be a link generated that you can use. Mine looked like this (It is an empty file and it's not a real link so I'm not worried about using real values for demonstration):

```
https://company.sharepoint.com/teams/folder/folder/folder/Test.xlsx?d=wb9d2ce64a09342c38047efa17f828458&csf=1&web=1&e=2emtWu&nav=MTJfQTJfezQ1QTc5MTc1LUU1QzItNEQxQS1CMjcyLTIzMDgzMUQ2NUY1Rn0
```

The parameters for the query string in the URL appear to be:

- d
- csf
- web
- e
- nav

## Manipulating the URL manually

I found [this site](https://cresyl.eu/en/office-365/understanding-how-share-links-are-built/) explaining the usage.

> E. This parameter section is added by default behind each share-link.
>
> - d= xxxx – this will help creating a unique URL to allow opening the file in the browser. If you remove this parameter, you’ll get a download request. This parameter is only added when you share with People with existing access.
> - Csf=1 – added when sharing with People with existing access
> - Web=1 – opens the file in the browser
> - E= xxxx – The purpose of this parameter isn’t really known; if you remove it, the Share will work the same way.

### Reducing the URL

I tested with my URL and I was able to still link to the specified cell after removing `d` and `e`, so you may not even need them. `csf` and `web` always `= 1`.

So the URL can be reduced down to:

`https://company.sharepoint.com/teams/folder/folder/folder/Test.xlsx?csf=1&web=1&nav=MTJfQTJfezQ1QTc5MTc1LUU1QzItNEQxQS1CMjcyLTIzMDgzMUQ2NUY1Rn0`

### Nav parameter

Now we need to figure out `nav`. My value was `MTJfQTJfezQ1QTc5MTc1LUU1QzItNEQxQS1CMjcyLTIzMDgzMUQ2NUY1Rn0`.

#### Base64 decoded

I recognized this may be [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded so I [decoded](https://www.base64decode.org/) it, resulting in `12_A2_{45A79175-E5C2-4D1A-B272-230831D65F5F}`. This is promising as `A2` was the cell that I linked to. The other values remain constant for the same file.

Lo and behold, I generated another link to cell `A3`. The resulting URL gave me:

- nav = `MTJfQTNfezQ1QTc5MTc1LUU1QzItNEQxQS1CMjcyLTIzMDgzMUQ2NUY1Rn0`
- Decoded is `12_A3_{45A79175-E5C2-4D1A-B272-230831D65F5F}`

This gets me the cell I wanted to link to `A3`.

To test more thoroughly, I created a new second file and tested. I also tried a second sheet.

For the different sections of `12_A3_{45A79175-E5C2-4D1A-B272-230831D65F5F}`:

- `12` = remained the same across files, so it should be constant
- `A3` = changes based on which cell you want
- `{45A79175-E5C2-4D1A-B272-230831D65F5F}` = changes based on the sheet

### Conclusion

You should be able to create this URL manually as long as you can generate the link the first time (or for however many sheets you wish to link to) to get the `nav` value and change the cell and/or sheet from there. You will also need to do Base64 encoding.

Comment: great idea. Unfortunately, I'd like to create the links in VBA and this doesn't seem to be human-readable. I'll try tomorrow, if I can figure out, how to use this query.

Comment: @KasparJohannes Ah, I was wondering if that was the case. Yeah this is not very human readable or easily recreated manually. I did find some info on this however: https://cresyl.eu/en/office-365/understanding-how-share-links-are-built/. It explains the `d`, `csf`, `web`, and `e` parameters. I tested with my URL and I was able to achieve the same result after removing `d` and `e`, so you may not even need them. `csf` and `web` always `= 1` so we only need to figure out `nav`

Comment: Good news, I figured out `nav`. Updated the answer accordingly. Now the difficulty may lie in achieving this in VBA

Comment: I tested it, it works. Thanks for the reverse engineering! I wonder why they had to overcomplicate something that simple...

Comment: When linking to a single cell (or cell range), the nav version is `12`; when linking to a whole sheet, it's `15`. I haven't found any other values for that field yet.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

> `=HYPERLINK("https://company.sharepoint.com/teams/folder/folder/folder/filename.xlsm#sheetname!a22")`

- If the location is internal to your current workbook, then use:

  - `=HYPERLINK("#sheetname!a22")`
- If the location is in a different workbook and you can open the workbook containing the hyperlink (origin) in the desktop app, then use:

  - `` =HYPERLINK("[`https://company.sharepoint.com/teams/folder/folder/folder/filename.xlsm`]sheetname!a22") ``
    which will open the target in a browser window. This formula will **not** work in excel online worksheets used as the origin.
- Otherwise I haven't found any working combination other than the manual link creation already discussed above if you want to link to an external workbook specific cell using only excel online. Given that you would need to use BASE64 conversions you're stuck with either:

  - Making a macro enabled workbook and leveraging VBA to do the conversions or
  - Doing the BASE64 conversions manually

> - Neither of these was an option for my use case because:
>
>   - I had thousands of links to create so wasn't willing to spend the time doing all those conversions manually
>   - My employer doesn't allow .xlsm on the web

Comment: Did you write this yourself or is this A.I.-generated?

Comment: I wrote this myself